# How do I set Youtube iframe volume from an outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, iframe, youtube

I'm generating A youtube Iframe using react-youtube

```
return (<Youtube
    id="video-player"
    videoId={id}
    opts={config}
    onReady={_onReady}
/>);
```

My embedded player has no controls since it is a background overlay. Instead of reacting to player events, I want to change the video's volume using a custom slider on my site.

My problem is accessing the Youtube iframe in order to make the API call.

I want to do something like:

```
player.setVolume(event.target.value);
```

Where player is the Youtube iframe and the event is the value of my custom slider.

I tried accessing the Iframe using

```
let video = document.getElementById("video-player");
video.contentWindow.setVolume(20);
```

Which looks like it can work, but I get this error:

```
SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "setVolume" on cross-origin object
```

Seems like I can't access the iFrame this way.

It's a react project, and the library I'm using is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setVolume), you should be able to do this:

```
// callback method for the YouTube component
_onReady(event) {
    // store the player somewhere safe
    this.setState({
        "player": event.target
    });
}
```

Then you can change the volume by doing this:

```
// your volume value should be stored in the state
this.state.player.setVolume(this.state.volume);
```

The reason your code is not working is because you cannot access content inside an iframe that is in a different domain. You can do a lot of nasty things if it is possible.

Comment: I set my Redux state using this method and now I can access the variable anywhere. Thanks!